# Changing Commerce Credit Card option to read something else

Tags: commerce

I have two radio options in my form for payment: the first says 'credit card' and the second says 'cheque' (I'm using the PayPal wpp and Cheque modules). The Cheque option is easy enough to change to say something else ('send me an invoice') and I changed that in the store > config > cheque settings.

But, does anyone know how or where to change the text for the 'Credit Card' option. I want to add more information about how we process it to the label itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alter the form that has the `form_id` of `commerce_checkout_form_review`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_commerce_checkout_form_review_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
 $form['commerce_payment']['payment_method']['#options']['commerce_payment_example|commerce_payment_commerce_payment_example'] = t('AWESOME PAYMENT');
}
```

The `#options` array will hold a list of payment methods that are keyed by the `payment_method` followed by a pipe (`|`) and then an `instance_id`. Just update the title accordingly.